# PHP add text to string at certain positions -issue

Tags: php, string, substr

I'm trying to insert text to string at certain positions (before letter "b" in this case), but for some reason the code I have only insert text (" test ")at the last position/occurance.

```
<?php
$str = "aabaaaaabaaaaab";
$needle = "b";
$teststr = " test ";
$lastPos = 0;
$positions = array();


while (($lastPos = strpos($str, $needle, $lastPos))!== false) {
$positions[] = $lastPos;
$lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($needle);
}

for ($i=0;$i<count($positions);$i++) {
$newstring = substr_replace($str,$teststr,$positions[$i],0);
}

echo $newstring;
?>`
```

this produces the following output: aabaaaaabaaaaa test b
when the desired one whould be: aa test aaaaa test aaaaa test b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `$str` as input for `substring_replace`, but you don't modify `$str` anywhere. Obviously only the last replacement will show. You can, for example, use `$newstring` as input for `substring_replace`, but then you positions are no longer correct. This can be avoided by making the replacements from right to left:

```
//snip

$newstring = $str;
for ($i = count($positions) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  $newstring = substr_replace($newstring, $teststr, $positions[$i], 0);
}

echo $newstring;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been banging my head against the wall with this issue for hours now!

Answer (score 0):

Would regular expressions work for you?

```
<?php
$str = "aabaaaaabaaaaab";
echo preg_replace('~b~', ' test b', $str);
```

Comment: It probably would, but I try to avoid regex at all cost. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "aabaaaaabaaaaab";
$needle = "b";
$teststr = " test ";
$lastPos = 0;
$positions = explode($needle, $str);
foreach($positions as $k=>$v) {
    $positions[$k]=$v.$teststr.$needle;
}
$positions=implode($positions);
echo $positions;
```

Try This

Comment: Thanks mate, I tried this code also, but I found that it adds a additional "test b" in the end. Ie. the result is: aa test baaaaa test baaaaa test b test b.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work

```
$str = "aabaaaaabaaaaab";
$needle = "b";
$teststr = " test ";

for ($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++) {
    if($str[$i]==$needle ){
        echo $teststr.$str[$i]; 
    }else{
        echo $str[$i];
    }
}

echo $newstring;

**Output** 
aa test baaaaa test baaaaa test b
```